# Parse log file (json)

Tags: json, database, ssis

I have a log file FileName.log that contain rows(see below).
how can I parse it to database (as a table column (create_date,x,l,d....)) in the fast\Best way (Even with SSIS it will be beast) ?
10X.

```
    TRACE 2016-10-19 09:45:05,253 {"x":"0.2466432000","l":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)","a":"GUsActions","u":"11138a3f-f65b-4ab9-8f57-06f2bc0533a5","i":"127.0.0.1","s":"GTA-A","e":"start"}
    TRACE 2016-10-19 09:45:05,503 {"x":"0.0017499000","d":"Tv","q":"SELECT","t":"gres_ips","l":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)","a":"GUsActions","u":"11138a3f-f65b-4ab9-8f57-06f2bc0533a5","i":"127.0.0.1","s":"GTA-A","e":"db"}
    TRACE 2016-10-19 09:45:06,175 {"x":"0.0115821000","l":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)","a":"GUsActions","u":"11138a3f-f65b-4ab9-8f57-06f2bc0533a5","i":"127.0.0.1","s":"GTA-A","e":"cb"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found to parse json using .net is [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) it may help you

Comment: Using json.net in SSIS requires you to register it with the GAC. Some production servers may be restrictive, and also this add a step in the deployment process.Instead `JavascriptSerializer` can be used that doesn't require a GAC installation as it is already in the available .Net Framework in the Scripting Component / Script Task.